# Connecting an old Mac to home entertainment system

Tags: itunes, audio, video, appletv, hdmi

I have an old MacBook Pro, with DVI-out video, analog audio (earphone and speaker ports), and of course USB. I'm using it to manage my iTunes library, but the only way to play iTunes content on my home entertainment system is via Wi-Fi to an Apple TV box.

My question: Is there a viable way to connect the Mac to an open HDMI port on my home system? I know that DVI-to-HDMI is video only, so I'd have to find out how to add the audio -- which is the whole point of the exercise! (Is there any such thing as an analog-to-HDMI or USB-to-HDMI audio adapter?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  It's very easy.  You need to get a "DVI to HDMI with audio" adapter.  The way it works is that it takes the two separate signals, digital video and audio, and combines them on the HDMI signal which supports the audio.

Here's one from [Startech](http://amzn.to/1jVNMXa) that worked really well for me.

[image: Input]
[image: Output]

If you notice, the DVI and RCA Audio is on the Input side and the HDMI is on the Output side.  These are **not** bidirectional; meaning it will not work in reverse.  So, it will take a DVI and audio and convert to HDMI.  It won't "break out" HDMI to DVI and audio.